Compactness and closed sets
I'm struggling with the proof (in the book Analisi Matematica 1 Pagani-Salsa) of the Heine-Borel theorem, the theorem states:
Given $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then   $E$ is compact $\iff$ $E$ is closed and bounded
The proof (of the closeness of $E$ knowing that $E$ is compact) goes like this:
Let $x \in C_E$ (where $C_E$ is the complementary of $E$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$), then for every $y \in E$ take a neighbourhood of $x$ ($U_y$) and a neighbourhood of $y$ ($V_y$) such that $U_y \cap V_y = \emptyset$. Now every point of E is cointained in the union of $\{V_y\}_{y\in E}$ and so by compactness of E, there exist a finite subset of $\{V_y\}_{y\in E}$, $S = \{V_{y_1}, \dots ,V_{y_n} \}$ such that  $E \subset S$, now take $U = U_{y_1} \cap \dots \cap U_{y_n}$, $ E \cap U = \emptyset$, and since $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, $C_E$ is open, and so $E$ is closed. I don't understand the need of the sequence $U_{y_k}$ to be finite in order to be disjointed to $E$.
I'm aware of this answer but i don't want another proof, i want to know why this proof is true.

By the construction of $U_y$ and $V_y$ ($y \in E$), as $\{V_y\}_{y\in E}$ is a cover of $E$, for each subcover $\{V_{y'}\}_{y'\in E} \subseteq \{V_y\}_{y\in E}$ of $E$ you have that $\bigcap_{y'\in E} U_{y'} \subseteq C_E$.
The need of finding a finite family $\{U_{y_1}, \dots U_{y_n}\}$ is to have assured that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n U_{y_k}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ (the finite intersection of neighborhoods of a point is a neighborhood of the point). So, you would have a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $C_E$.
